# The Transversality Theorem for C^r manifolds?

Tags: differential-topology, transversality

I am studying **The Transversality Theorem** introduced in Sect. 2.3 of the book "Differential Topology" by Guillemin, V and Pollack, A. It seems that the manifolds and submanifolds considered there are all assumed to be smooth, so I am curious if the smoothness assumption can be relaxed.

More precisely, I was wondering: whether this theorem would hold also for C^r (r\ge 1) manifolds? Are there any references about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at Hirsch's *Differential Topology*, chapter 3.

Comment: Thank you again, Prof. Shifrin. (This post is from xiaoliang ^_^). I already took a look at Hirsch's book after you suggested. There, I found a C^r version of the parametric transversality theorem I was concerned with, i.e. theorem 2.7 in chapter 3 of the book.